# 特定の物体のオプティカルフローを計算したい

Tags: python, opencv

Webカメラを用いて直径5mmの金属球が動く様子を撮影し、金属球の速度を測定したいと思っています。
その方法として、python、opencvのオプティカルフローを用いようと考えています。

その第一段階として、

http://labs.eecs.tottori-u.ac.jp/sd/Member/oyamada/OpenCV/html/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html

を引用し、以下を記載したのですが、まず金属球のみのフローを検出するところで、躓いています。
opencvの機能としてオプティカルフローの検出範囲を絞るもしくは四角や丸で囲んだ箇所のみ検出することは可能でしょうか？ご教授お願い致します。

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('speed_sample.mp4')

# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.5,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

# Create some random colors
color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))

# Take first frame and find corners in it
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)

# Create a mask image for drawing purposes
mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

while(1):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # calculate optical flow
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

    # Select good points
    good_new = p1[st==1]
    good_old = p0[st==1]

    # draw the tracks
    for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
        a,b = new.ravel()
        c,d = old.ravel()
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
    img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: 記述されているソースコードが重複して貼り付けられているので修正をお願いします。「検出範囲を絞る」とは、例えば、元画像（640ｘ480）に対して、(100，100)-（200，200）の座標範囲に絞り込んで、処理を実施するというイメージでしょうか？

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました、修正しました。おっしゃる通りです。背景の物体も測定しているので、金属球のみの情報を得られるように絞り込むことはできないかと考えています。

Comment: もっとも単純な方法は、処理に引き渡す画像にマスクしてしまうことです。マスク画像は任意の範囲（円、矩形、多角形）の二値化画像で、処理を無効化したい箇所をマスク画像をもとに単色に塗りつぶしてしまえば、「動きのない」部分となるため、フローも検出されません。ただし、そのマスク範囲の設定が妥当なのかは目的によって留意する必要があります。

Comment: 計算したい範囲の部分画像をフロー計算に用いればよいだけでは？（いずれにしろ，勝手に作ってしまった「データ無し領域」との境界による影響を考える必要はある）

Comment: それはそれとして，【各時刻においてどこが「金属球」なのかがわかるのであれば】，フロー計算範囲を絞ることは単なる計算コストの削減でしかないので，計算量が問題だというのでもないならば別にそこを絞る必要性は無いのでは…？

Comment: Takahiro Funahashi　様　シンプルな方法で簡単にできそうですね。ご提案ありがとうございます。
 
fana　様　確かに速度が知りたいだけなのでフローにこだわる必要がないのかもしれません。ご提案ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご提案いただいた、無効化したい箇所をマスクする方法を試してみます。
ありがとうございました。